# Was Titan A.E. officially linked to Freelancer?

Tags: inspiration

I recently saw the movie Titan A.E., and whilst being a mildly enjoyable bit of cartoon escapism, what struck me immediately was, to a remarkable degree, the similarity to the game Freelancer.

Was one an official tribute to, or tie in, of the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no known official connection between Titan A.E. and Freelancer other than that they both have a similar plot.  While they were released within a few years of each other, the production companies of the two separate works, [Fox Animation Studios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Animation_Studios) and [Digital Anvil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Anvil), don't appear to have any connections.

It maybe that one work influenced the author(s) of the other work, which is one of the typical ways writing tropes evolve.